# Set Node Size with the amount of edges in cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'm trying to draw a molecular similarity network using cytoscape.js.
I want to set node size to the amount of edges in network.
Now I have network data as JSON Format.
I want to now that how set each node size using node degree.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your stylesheet, you can define the style according to degree.

e.g.:

```
node[[degree = 0]] { /* ... */ }
node[[degree >= 1]][[degree <= 3]] { /* ... */ }
node[[degree >= 4]] { /* ... */ }
```

Refer to the [data selectors](http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/#selectors/data) and use the [[metadata]] double square brackets.

If you need more precision (i.e. on the JS code level rather than the stylesheet level):

If your graph is static, you could add a `degree` data attribute to each node and use a mapper in your stylesheet with that attribute.  If your graph is dynamic, you could use the same approach but update the `degree` attribute as the graph is modified.

Comment: It would be awesome if we could use the metadata in mapData as it can be used in the stylesheet. Do you think it would be realistic to implement that?

Comment: @Melanie Use a function and you can specify whatever mapping you'd like.

Comment: May be I am not doing it right, but this doesn't work for me.. I tried ```node[[degree < 10]] { 'size': 1 },
node[[degree >= 10]] {'size': 4}```

Answer (score 1):

some dynamic styling behaviour that worked out pretty well for me:

```
{
  selector: 'node',
  style: {
    width: function(ele){ return ele.degree(); },
    height: function(ele){ return ele.degree(); }
  }
}
```

same but with some sort of a factor applied

```
{
  selector: 'node',
  style: {
    width: function(ele){ return Math.max(1, Math.ceil(ele.degree()/2)) * 10; },
    height: function(ele){ return Math.max(1, Math.ceil(ele.degree()/2)) * 10; },
  }
}
```